# Why is this graph showing up twice in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, lattice

````
```{r scatterplot, fig.width=14, fig.height=14, echo=FALSE, results="hide"}

histogram(
  ~factor(
    format(df_ian$newDate,"%b"),
    levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
  ) | factor(
    format(newDate,"'%y")
  ),
  data=df_ian, layout=(c(3,6)),
  main="Flood Counts by year and month",
  ylab="Flood Count",
  xlab="Year"
)
```
````

When I knit, the histogram show up twice. What am I missing here?

Comment: it would be helpful to folks to include working code. `histogram` isn't in base R. Is this lattice? Some htmlwidget? Plus, we don't have `df_ian` so it's impossible to reproduce.

Comment: @hrbrmstr histogram is in lattice, yes.

Answer (score 0):

@hrbrmstr is correct, we cannot reproduce the problem. Because of that, I cannot but advance only a suspect: you are plotting a histogram for every factor of the second argument of the function.

Consider a simple dataset:

```
dt  <- data.frame(gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), c(4, 2) ), trans = rep(c("Car", "Bus",
"Bike"), c(3, 2, 1) ))

library(lattice)
histogram(~trans | gender, data = dt )
```

[image: Double hist]

Lattice functions rely on a formula. In the example above you plot the variable `trans` by every level of the factor variable `gender`. How you can suppose, `gender` has two levels, male and female, hence we will have two plots.

Otherwise, if you remove the operator `|`, you will have a single histogram for the variable `trans`.

```
histogram(~trans, data = dt )
```

[image]